# Collision prediction of 2 moving objects

Tags: unity, collision-prediction

I have to 2 objects with `Collider2D`. Both objects are moving, in the very next frame they will either overlap each other or not. How to predict if they would collide on the next frame? I'm thinking of instantiating a temporary object then use `collider.Overlap()`. But maybe there are better ways to do this.

Comment: Do you know anything in advance about the shapes of the objects' colliders?

Comment: Adding to the comment of @DMGregory if you collider is circular, for example, you could just extrapolate the current motion and compare the extrapolated collider center points to the radii

Comment: No, it's a polygon collider